# Email to Sms Sending Script using number@service_provider

Tags: php

I have use one service like sending sms to user like number@service_provider (123456@pcs.asa.com) and i am sending a message  as email and working fine but getting this message one day or two day after not immediately and also i think this service use only in USA so any one have any idea why i am getting late response by this service.

I am using mine-construct to sending mail and i am using this site for getting provider info [Service Provider Info](http://www.data24-7.com/textat.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking into a reliable SMS gateway service such as [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com)? I have used their services and have found them to be very reliable as well as having various SDK's prebuilt for different programming languages.